# Error installing mysqldb: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask-mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mysql-python, flask-mysql

[The error i receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B11qq.png)

I get this error trying to install mysqldb with pip. I got a response that I damaged the python files and should remove and re-install python on a different website. So I removed python via the control panel and downloaded it again. I'm not sure if it's enough or is it the right way to go but the issue still remains.
By the way, I installed python in a different folder before and then changed it manually by moving the files by dragging them, could that be the reason the files are damaged.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

From the error that you receive seems that you have connection error and for that reason you cannot fetch the repository. Try to install **ssl** module with `pip install ssl`. Because if you look the first warning you can see this `pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available`.